# Getting conditionally value on another variable

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- tribble(~ id,  ~ year, ~ born, ~income,
                 1,    2015,     -1,    3005,
                 2,    2015,     -1,    3500,
                 3,    2015,     -1,    3090,
                 4,    2015,     -1,    3000,
                 5,    2015,     NA,     700,
                 1,    2016,      0,    2005,
                 2,    2016,      0,    2500,
                 3,    2016,      0,    2090,
                 4,    2016,      0,    2050,
                 5,    2005,     NA,     900,
                 1,    2017,      1,    1005,
                 2,    2017,      1,    1500,
                 3,    2017,      1,    1090,
                 4,    2017,      1,    1000,
                 5,    2017,     NA,    1500)
```

I want to create another variable (e.g., "pre_income" that only takes the value of the variable income when born is -1.

```
df_wanted <- tribble(~ id,  ~ year, ~ born, ~income, ~pre_income,
                        1,    2015,     -1,    3005,        3005,       
                        2,    2015,     -1,    3500,        3500,
                        3,    2015,     -1,    3090,        3090,
                        4,    2015,     -1,    3000,        3000,
                        5,    2015,     NA,     700,          NA,
                        1,    2016,      0,    2005,        3005,
                        2,    2016,      0,    2500,        3500,
                        3,    2016,      0,    2090,        3090,
                        4,    2016,      0,    2050,        3000,
                        5,    2016,     NA,     900,          NA,
                        1,    2017,      1,    1005,        3005,
                        2,    2017,      1,    1500,        3500,
                        3,    2017,      1,    1090,        3090,
                        4,    2017,      1,    1000,        3000,
                        5,    2017,     NA,    1500,          NA)
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

The solution provided above does not work when there are NAs in the born variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can `group_by` `id` and get the income value when `born == -1`.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(pre_income = income[born == -1]) %>% 
  ungroup

# A tibble: 15 x 5
      id  year  born income pre_income
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1  2015    -1   3005       3005
 2     2  2015    -1   3500       3500
 3     3  2015    -1   3090       3090
 4     4  2015    -1   3000       3000
 5     5  2015    NA    700         NA
 6     1  2016     0   2005       3005
 7     2  2016     0   2500       3500
 8     3  2016     0   2090       3090
 9     4  2016     0   2050       3000
10     5  2005    NA    900         NA
11     1  2017     1   1005       3005
12     2  2017     1   1500       3500
13     3  2017     1   1090       3090
14     4  2017     1   1000       3000
15     5  2017    NA   1500         NA
```

data

```r
df <- tribble(~ id,  ~ year, ~ born, ~income,
              1,    2015,     -1,    3005,
              2,    2015,     -1,    3500,
              3,    2015,     -1,    3090,
              4,    2015,     -1,    3000,
              5,    2015,     NA,     700,
              1,    2016,      0,    2005,
              2,    2016,      0,    2500,
              3,    2016,      0,    2090,
              4,    2016,      0,    2050,
              5,    2005,     NA,     900,
              1,    2017,      1,    1005,
              2,    2017,      1,    1500,
              3,    2017,      1,    1090,
              4,    2017,      1,    1000,
              5,    2017,     NA,    1500)
```

Comment: Thanks! But this only works if there's a born == -1 in each group, it is possible to have NAs.

Comment: It should work with NAs as well, see my edited answer